# Does Google c++ testing allow for creation of stubs

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Does Google c++ testing allow for creation of stubs either automatically or manually?

Comment: What do you mean by stubs? The methods and objects that a test case uses?

Comment: ..or do you mean mock objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Test is a unit testing framework in the XUnit style.  Google Mock (http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) is a related project that provides stubs and mocks.  If you are looking for a C++ test framework that is in the BDD style you can look at Igloo (http://igloo-testing.org/).

Answer (score 0):

googletest doesn't.
However, you can use googlemock for that.